# expressjs oracledb { [Error: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor] errorNum: 12514, offset: 0 }

Tags: node.js, oracle, express, node-oracledb

I connect with DBeaver to Oracle Database Express Edition 11g successfully

[image: successfully]

but when i want to connect with nodeJS
[image: error]

my code is

````
const oracleApp = express();

const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const config = {
  user: 'TEST',
  password: 'TEST',
  connectString: 'localhost:1521/XE'
};


async function getStudents() {
  let conn;
  try {
    conn = await oracledb.getConnection(config);
    const result = await conn.execute(
      'select * from students'
    );
    console.log(result.rows[0]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Ouch!', err);
  } finally {
    if (conn) { // conn assignment worked, need to close
      await conn.close();
    }
  }
}

getStudents();```
````

Answer (score 0):

you need to send us result of `lsnrctl status`

try `localhost:1521:XE`

Comment: I try 'localhost:1521:XE' but same issue

Comment: which connector are you using on the node.js side?

Comment: with epressjs i use

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html#oracle

Oracle
Module: oracledb

Installation
NOTE: See installation prerequisites.